Show timestamps for each line in the log of github actions workflow
To show timestamps for each line in the log of gitlab pipeline, I use below code:
.job:
  before_script:
    - PS4='+ $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T.%3N")\011' # enable timestamps
    - set -x

How to achieve the same in github actions workflow?
I used below code to no avail:
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Show timestamps
      run: |
        PS4='+ $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T.%3N")\011'
        set -x
      shell: bash


Can you also mention the desired output of getting the timestamp for your logs??
